# Understanding dual of $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Denote by $\ell^{\infty}$ the Banach space of bounded sequences (real or complex). By an elementary argument, the dual space of $\ell^{\infty}$ consists of all bounded finitely additive signed measures on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space) or [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Enspronk/math451/Lone_dual.pdf). On the other hand, since $\ell^{\infty}$ is the same as $C(\beta\mathbb{N})$ where $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is the space of ultrafilters (or the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$), by Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem the dual of $\ell^{\infty}=C(\beta\mathbb{N})$ consists of regular Borel measure on $\beta\mathbb{N}$. My questions are:

1. This means a *finitely additive* measure on $\mathbb{N}$ corresponds to a *countably additive* measure on $\beta\mathbb{N}$. How can that be? How to understand this? Is there a direct discription of this correspondence?
2. It seems the space of finitely additive measures is given the norm of total variation. Can we view it as a subspace of $B(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mathbb{R})$ (all bounded maps from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{R}$) and give it the sup norm?
3. The obvious (countably additive) measures on $\beta\mathbb{N}$ are the point measures (either at some natural number or at some ultrafilter) or their countable weighted sum (I guess these already contain the space $\ell^1$). What are some non-trivial examples? Can we "classify" these measures, whatever that means?

Comment: See my remarks of 8 years ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/392719/442

Comment: As $\ell^\infty$ is the dual of $\ell^1$, the latter is also canonically a subspace of the dual of $\ell^\infty$. There is no hope at all of classifying measures as asked. You cannot give concrete examples of the extra measures (due to AC etc).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I agree that it doesn't seem plausible, since classifying these measures is probably more difficult than classifying ultrafilters (there *is* some work on that topic though). Can we at least understand these measures in terms of ultrafilters?

Comment: Dear @GEdgar, a similar question came up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656244/121671). As the OP here states, there are elements in $\ell^*_\infty$ which are not countably additive (Banach limits for example) while all elements in $C^*(\beta\mathbb{N})$ are $\sigma$-aditive. I guess that the confusion is that one my think (erroneously) that an element $\mu$ in $\ell^*$ is the restriction to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ of a (signed) Radon measure on $\mathscr{B}(\beta\mathbb{N})$. Do you have any idea on  how a signed-Borelmeasure on $\beta\mathbb{N}$ relates to an element in $\ell_\infty$?